# facebook share and opengraph

Tags: facebook

I'm managing a video blog.
The blog contains a main youtube video on the homepage and several thumbnail images of other videos elsewhere.

I have a share button for the main page and the single posts pages and have added opengraph to specify the used image.

For some reason facebook ignores my opengraph image and uses othe images it finds in the page...

the header looks like this: (for the homepage)

```
    <!-- Facebook Opengraph -->
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="155967927783206" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://mttv.co.il/2010/12/%d7%9e%d7%a4%d7%92%d7%a9-%d7%a1%d7%99%d7%99%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%92%d7%a0%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%93%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%aa%d7%99%d7%94%d7%9d-1959-2010-%d7%91%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%aa/"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="מפגש סייעות גננות לדורתיהם 1959-2010 במעלות" />

    <meta property="og:description" content="מפגש מיוחד של סייעות גננות במעלות לדורותיהם   משנת פעילות 1959 ועד 2010
אירגון  המפגש באחריות הגב' שוש דהן ונערך בחצר מוזיאון המייסדים  במעלות ע&quot;ש יעקב חזן ז&quot;ל
עריכה וצילום
שרביט שלמה
08.12.10 
" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mttv.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Gvi91UEjCAw_mid-135x77.jpg" />
```

The website address is: http://mttv.co.il

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should ask this question again in <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a> for a better response.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of the URL that you have in your Share link the Open Graph image tag seems to be missing.

Facebook's URL Linter to verify your tags are working on the URLs you want to share:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint?url=http://mttv.co.il/2011/01/%25d7%2594%25d7%2599%25d7%259c%25d7%2595%25d7%259c%25d7%2594-%25d7%25a9%25d7%259c-%25d7%2594%25d7%2591%25d7%2591%25d7%2590-%25d7%25a1%25d7%259c%25d7%2599-%25d7%2591%25d7%259e%25d7%25a2%25d7%259c%25d7%2595%25d7%25aa/

FB wil cache the tags too, so use the URL Linter every time you update them.